# Magento 2 - How to get product in a block

Tags: magento2, product, registry, category-listing

I'm trying to insert a block in default.xml layout so I created my **app/code/Mainf/Stickers/view/frontend/layout/default.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Mainf_Stickers::css/mainf-stickers.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block name="category.discount.sticker" class="Mainf\Stickers\Block\Discount" template="Mainf_Stickers::discount.phtml" cacheable="false" after="-" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

and my block file (**app/code/Mainf/Stickers/Block/Discount.php**):

```
<?php

namespace Mainf\Stickers\Block;

class Discount extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_product = null;

    protected $_coreRegistry = null;
    protected $_productFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return Product
     */
    protected function _getProduct()
    {
        if (!$this->_product) {
            $this->_product = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product');
        }

        return $this->_product;
    }

    public function isDiscounted()
    {
        $idProd = $this->_getProduct()->getData('entity_id');

        return true;
    }
}
```

When I call a category page, `$this->_coreRegistry->registry('product')` is empty, different from I call a product page.

How could I get "current product" when it loading a category page?

Is there any alternate method to get product apart from registry?

Answer (score 1):

Try bellow code

```
<?php

namespace Mainf\Stickers\Block;

class Discount extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_product = null;

    protected $_registry;
    protected $_productFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {       
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {       
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }

    public function isDiscounted()
    {
        $idProd = $this->getCurrentProduct()->getData('entity_id');

        return true;
    }
}
```

Display current product data in your template (custom.phtml) file

```
if ($currentProduct = $block->getCurrentProduct()) {
    echo $currentProduct->getName() . '<br />';
    echo $currentProduct->getSku() . '<br />';
    echo $currentProduct->getId() . '<br />';       
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry @Abdul but.. what is the difference from your code and mine?
I've already tried with _'current_product'_ instead of _'product'_ without success.
The problem is that `\Magento\Framework\Registry $registry` is empty in my block.

Answer (score 1):

you can't get "the" product on a category page. How should Magento know, which product you mean on a category page, since there could be X products.

On a category page, only 'current_category' will be in the registry

the current_product registry key is registered in the product view controller when you are accessing a specific product through the frontend

Comment: Ok @David Verholen, you're right.. I know!
But, is there any alternate method to get product apart from registry?
This is the real question..

Comment: Yes, but which product?

Comment: For every category products, I have to check one of their attribute; so, every category products.

Comment: you can extend your block from Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct . This way, you have the getLoadedProductCollection() function available which gives you the products that are loaded on the site

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    namespace Vendor\CustomShirt\Block;


    use \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View;

    class MyClass extends View
    {

    }
```